# How to store image into mysql with mybatis?

Tags: java, mysql, blob, mybatis

Could anybody let me know how to store the image into MySQL with the mybatis? I can store image into MySQL with jdbc code, but I wish using the MyBatis to do the same things, but it does not work fine, My mapper as below:

```
<mapper namespace = "myinfo.beans.Resources">
<!-- For Resources Table -->
<insert id="insertResource" parameterType="myinfo.beans.Resources">  
insert into resources(res_name, res_type, res_content,res_path) values (#{res_name, jdbcType=VARCHAR},#{res_type, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{res_content, javaType=byte[], jdbcType=BLOB, typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.BlobTypeHandler}, #{res_path, jdbcType=VARCHAR})  
</insert>
</mapper>
```

and the entity is

```
public class Resources {
    private int res_id;
    private String res_name;
    private String res_type;
    private byte[] res_content;
    private String res_path;
...
}
```

the dao code is:

```
public void insertResource (Resources res){
    session = sqlfactory.openSession();
    try {
        session.insert("insertResource",res);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ResourcesDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }        
}
```

and I call the dao with:

```
   public void createNewResource() {
        try {
            File file = new File("d:/DSC_0009.JPG");
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] photodata = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fis.read(photodata);
            Resources res = new Resources();
            res.setRes_content(photodata);
            res.setRes_name("Sunny_Ho");
            res.setRes_type("photho");
            res.setRes_path("d:/");
            res_dao.insertResource(res);     
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ResourcesController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
          catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(ResourcesController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
    }
```

my table is

```
CREATE TABLE `resources` (
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `res_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `res_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `res_content` longblob,
  `res_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`res_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I run these codes with main class, there is not any error appeared, but the record cannot be inserted.

Please help me point out what's wrong for it, thanks